# How can I make sure render is completed in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In React there is a `setState` API, we can provide a callback which will only be invoked when `render` is completed. Such guarantee is really useful in my scenario because I need to do something based on the native DOM. DO NOT tell me it is bad practice to take advantage of native DOM, there are some APIs React not provided such as `getBoundingClientRect`. I can only rely on `getBoundingClientRect` when `render` is complete for sure

In terms of redux, `setState` is hidden away, so I can not get such guarantee.
I tried out a solution which seems to get what I want

```
thunkedAction().then(()=>{
    somethingShouldAfterRender()
})
```

even though `thunkedAction` is synchronous originally, I make them async on purpose just because I need that callback. I naively suppose the callback is invoked when `render` is completed and it seems to be true

Can anyone confirm the idea or provide another solution?

Comment: why not using lifecycle method like CDidMount, CDidUpdate?

Comment: @MayankShukla The callback is related exclusively to that action, It hard to find a decent way to figure out when to trigger that callback in lifecycle hook

Comment: @MayankShukla I make sense though, A flag can be set to true before invoking the action, in lifecycle hood, check the flag and set the flag back to false.
I suppose redux is a big community, I want to know is such pattern of problem good discussed or not

Comment: So a better approach would be check the data that was updated by the thunkedAction in componentDidUpdate of the container, you could compare the previous prop and the current prop and decide what you want to do it the data changed I the data that you update is highly nested I would suggest you make use of ImmutableJS or provide a flag

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes I reckon lifecycle hood is more preferable. It sounds like even the creator of redux is uncertain if the action callback is reliable or not, it involved around how React handle state internally
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/705

Comment: Yeah you sure cannot rely on the callback from action creators and lifecycle method should be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Like componentWillMount()
there is a callback **componentDidMount()** which will be called after the **render** is completed for the first time. Because after that **componentDidUpdate()** will be called on updating component's state resulting in rendering the diff.

So if you just want to doSomthing() after render is being called for the first time you can put that doSomething() in componentDidMount(). But if you want to do this after every time render() is being called you can put doSomething() in both of the callbacks.